# How can I get text content of multiple elements with Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my code:

```
def textfinder():
    try:
        textfinder1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("m-b-none").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
        print("no such element")
    print(textfinder1)
```

It works only when I use *find_element*. When I use find_element**s**, it gives me error *"list" object has no attribute "text"*.  I understand that it returns a list, but I just don’t know how to "read" it. When I remove *.text* from the command, I don’t get any error, but some weird data, but I need the text content of the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, when you do

```
text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("m-b-none").text
```

You will get the first element that is matched, and this element possesses, thanks to Selenium, an attribute whose name is `text`. *A contrario*, when you do

```
matched_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("m-b-none")
                                      ^
```

it will match all corresponding elements. Given that `matched_elements` is a list, and that this list is a Python-native one, (it is not, for example, a Selenium-modified object which has `text` as attribute), you will have to iter over it, and iteratively get the text of each element. As follows

```
texts = []
for matched_element in matched_elements:
    text = matched_element.text
    texts.append(text)
    print(text)
```

Or if you want to leave your code unchanged as possible, you can do it in one line:

```
texts = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("m-b-none")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to reference each like an element of a list. Something like this:

```
textfinder1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("m-b-none")

for elements in textfinder1:
    print elements.text
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `find_elements_by_class_name` returns a list, so you should do:

```
text = ''
textfinder1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("m-b-none")
for i in textfinder1:
  text += i.text + '\n' # Or whatever the way you want to concatenate your text
print(text)
```